# Why does a base class allows me to create an instance using a derived class constructor?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

suppose we have this class structure:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base class constructor has been called.");
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived class constructor has been called.");
    }
}
```

so, my question is simple: Why does C# let me to create an instance of the Base class using the constructor of the Derived Class?
for explample:
BaseClass instance = new DerivedClass();

I would also like to know what is the effect of doing it or what would the benefits be of doing that? I know that if I execute this code, the base class constructor gets called first and then the derived constructor because this follows the normal behavior of class inheritance.
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't; you're creating an instance of `DerivedClass` and storing a reference to that instance within a variable whose type is `BaseClass`. Any variable in C# (or virtually *any* object-oriented language) that is of type `T` can hold a reference (or pointer, depending on your language) to any object whose type is `T` or a type that derives from `T` at some point.

Doing this (in C#, anyway) has no effect whatsoever on how the object is constructed, so there is no "effect" in any strict sense.

Answer (score 3):

You are not creating an instance of the base class; you are creating an instance of the derived class and storing a reference to it in a variable that has the type of the base class.  A variable with a base type referencing an instance of the derived type is the basis of polymorphism.